# Conditional invocation of constructor

Tags: c++

Suppose some class `foo` has two custom constructors, say `foo::foo(bar const &)` and `foo::foo(baz const &)`. What would be considered good style for invoking either one depending on some condition. For example:

```
bar a;
baz b;
foo my_foo;
if (...) {
    my_foo = foo(a);
} else {
    my_foo = foo(b);
}
```

would require `foo` to be default constructible (which is not very sensible in the concrete case I have in mind) and is essentially wasting time (and memory) on the creation (and deletion) of the default-constructed temporary object. Because of scope, one cannot declare `my_foo` inside the if or else blocks.

An alternative would be to use a pointer and construct with `new`. This would be less efficient (indirection, heap allocation) and potentially unsafe (no guarantee pointer isn't dangling; need to `delete`, though the latter may be taken care of by using `std::unique_ptr`).

I found one way to do it:

```
foo my_foo = (...) ? foo(a) : foo(b);
```

which works because the ternary operator is guaranteed to be exhaustive and thus scope is not an issue.

I'm not a big fan of the ternary operator and might want to do some other things in the conditional blocks before invoking the ctors. Is there an elegant way to achieve the same thing with the traditional if-else syntax?

Comment: Unless your class has restrictions (not default constructible for example) then this is mostly a question of style and preference. You can wrap the thing in a function or lambda if you really just care about looks.

Comment: You can do this with a pointer, nullable type, or a movable type and a function (including lambda, see the excellent answer) returning the object instance. None require a default constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a lambda

```
const foo my_foo = [&] 
    {
          if (...) 
               return foo(a);
          else 
               return foo(b);
    } ();
```

Comment: Good thinking. I checked that when compiling with optimizations (GCC 7, -O3), this produces the same assembly as the version with the ternary operator, so the function call to the lambda is inlined.